# CONCAT two wstrings in codesys

Tags: codesys, structured-text, iec61131-3

I have the problem that the CONCAT(str1, str2) function does not take two wstrings and I have not found a concat function for wstring. So how should I do it?

I cannot convert the input to string and then back to wstring as I then loose information of the string. This `ws_textOut:=STRING_TO_WSTRING(CONCAT("E ", WSTRING_TO_STRING(ws_TextIn)));` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`WCONCAT`](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/NWDT1QpYIeHEaugA1Re2wNZq7kY%2FWCONCAT;product=Standard64;version=3.5.17.0) to concatenate them.